# Dataset in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have a page in my website where a users can edit the records - one of the fields is a dropdown list.
I've been told I can use this code below to populate the dropdown field. My question is this; if several people are working in the page is the System.Data.DataTable created unique to the user? Many thanks.

```
            Dim subjects As New System.Data.DataTable()

            Dim queryStringN As String = "SELECT [UKEY], [ClientContact] FROM [View_Contacts] with (NOLOCK) order by [ClientContact]"
            Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Databaseportal").ConnectionString)

                Try
                    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(queryStringN, con)
                    adapter.Fill(subjects)

                    Me.ProductionManager1.DataSource = subjects
                    Me.ProductionManager1.DataTextField = "ClientContact"
                    Me.ProductionManager1.DataValueField = "ClientContact"
                    Me.ProductionManager1.DataBind()
                    ' Handle the error
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End Using
```

Comment: Sorry just another thought - does the 'subjects' table created need emptying/deleting at any point? Thanks.

Comment: No - it will get disposed of when the page has finished executing.

Comment: Since subjects DT is a fresh instance of the DataTable class. So there is no need of emptying or deleting before filling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the page is requested, it will generate a `DataTable` that will be unique to that instance of the Page, so the answer to your question is Yes, it will be unique to the user.

Comment: Thanks Mike, another stupid question as my page has the dropdown listed 10 times is it possible to build the datatable and reuse it? Or am I looking at storing it in session? Thanks Again.

Comment: You can use the same datatable as a datasource for multiple controls on the same page. The datatable will live as long as it takes for the entire page to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks generic and same for every user. There is no filter which can bring different record set for different users.

```
SELECT [UKEY], [ClientContact] FROM [View_Contacts] with (NOLOCK) order by [ClientContact]
```

In nutshell, it will yield same dataset for every user on your webpage. The data inside the datatable will be same for every user.

Comment: The contents of the dataset will be the same for each user, but the datatable is not shared among users.

Comment: Thanks Karan, another stupid question as my page has the dropdown listed 10 times is it possible to build the datatable and reuse it? Or am I looking at storing it in session? Thanks Again.

Comment: Are you using the Dropdownlist 10 times on your page and binded to the same dataset ? Is that the case ? pls confirm.

Comment: Hi, building the dataset 10 times and binding to each dropdown list. thanks.

Comment: You should stick the Dropdownlist into the Repeater or DataList control. Prepare the dataset once only, and bind it to the DropdownList contorl in the ItemDataBount event handler of the Repeater control. This way you will only need to make the DB call once.